# How do you spin side to side using css3 animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

I have an image of a face. I want to spin/rotate it side to side. 20 degrees to the right and 20 degrees to the left.

So far this is my code:

```
<img class="image">
```

CSS

```
.image {

-webkit-animation:spin 1.8s linear infinite;

}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {

from { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
to { -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg); }

}
```

**I can get it to move one way, but how do I make it go back the other way?**

I was thinking it should work like this: spin **from** 0 deg **to** 20 deg **from** 20 deg **to** -20 degrees. I tried it but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would not be able to achieve it using `from` and `to` in animations but you can use the percentage option like below:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- For the first 50% of the animation duration (0-0.9s), it would rotate the image from 0 to 20 degrees.
- For the next 50% (50% - 100%), it would rotate the image from 20 degrees to -20 degrees.
- For the animation to have a more smoother look, you could also a rotate to 0 degree in between and at the end (as shown in Sample 2 below).
- If you want 0 to 20 alone to happen in a 1.8s window and 20 to -20 degrees to take another 1.8s then you can increase the animation duration to 3.6s in the `-webkit-animation` property value like below (at the end).

**Note:** I assume you are aware that with the `-webkit-` prefix, the animation effect would be seen only in webkit powered browsers. For Firefox, you would have to add `-moz-` for the animations, keyframes and transform properties and for future compliance you would have to add the standard un-prefixed versions also.

```
.image {
    -webkit-animation:spin 3.6s linear infinite;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/53q06og3/)

---

**Sample 2** - with a smoother rotation effect

```
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    25% { /* note that rotation from 0 to 20 deg happens in 25% time = 0.45 seconds. */
        -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }    
}
```

[**Demo for Sample 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/53q06og3/1/)

Comment: @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(20deg);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(-20deg);
    }
}This edition seems to be enough for smooth rotation

Comment: True mate, it does. But this kind of starts at -20 degree (in Opera) which is slightly different from the user's expectation and that is why I had not mentioned it. But in Firefox & Chrome, it seems to start at 0. Maybe some browser specific behavior. But I am confused as Opera and Chrome are both webkit powered :D

Comment: Actually it behaves the same way in Firefox and Chrome also but the problem was I had added a delay for testing purpose and that was causing the start at 0. So no browser differences there :)